# ValueError: too may values to unpack

Tags: python

Could anyone give some input on this please.

```
for line in oscars_file:
    if '-' in line:
        years,oscars=line.strip().split('-')
```

I'm getting this error in the terminal:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

An example from the oscars file is:

```
1975 - "One Flew over the Cuckoo's Nest"

1973 - "The Sting"
```

Comment: the code is correct (at least in my pc), check your **oscars file**, it looks there is a problem with it.

Answer (score 4):

Some of your text may contain more than 1 `'-'`. For that, you should do:

```
for line in oscars_file:
    if '-' in line:
        years,oscars=line.strip().split('-',1)
```

The `split('-',1)` makes only one split which is the first split which is what you want.

#### Examples

```
>>> s = '1-2-3-4'
>>> print s.split('-',1)
['1','2-3-4']
>>> print s.split('-',2)
['1','2','3-4']
```

Comment: Way better than my answer.  In fact, I'm going to delete my answer.

Comment: @user3046660, If the answer is what you wanted, you should click on the tick on the left side of the answer to select it as chosen. People are more likely to answer you if you chose an answer as the solution (http://stackoverflow.com/about )